# resolving model conflict between page and partial view in master page MVC?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a mvc site where the master page uses RenderPartial to return different views based on user roles. One of the partial view is inherited on a "SettingsModel" type. This results in a conflict with the underlying page which takes a different model. When it tries to render the page, it says "I'm expecting "settingsModel" but the incoming model is for the page. How can I resolve this conflict?

Answer (score 0):

you can use RenderAction method to render different partial pages having their own view models
[this article](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/11/24/renderpartial-vs-renderaction.aspx) explains difference b/w rederpartial and renderAction with pros and cons of each